# Why does Java BigDecimal return 1E+1?

Tags: java, floating-point, bigdecimal

Why does this code sometimes return 1E+1 whilst for other inputs (e.g. 17) the output is not printed in scientific notation?

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(doubleValue).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100d)).stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println("value: " + bigDecimal);
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

use [bigDecimal.toPlainString()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()):

```
 BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(100000.0)
                     .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100d))
                     .stripTrailingZeros();
 System.out.println("plain      : " + bigDecimal.toPlainString());
 System.out.println("scientific : " + bigDecimal.toEngineeringString());
```

outputs:

```
plain      : 10000000
scientific : 10E+6
```

Comment: +1 for providing an actual solution instead of "here is the problem" like I did. :)

Comment: Answers like this is what makes Stackoverflow great

Comment: but why stripTrailingZeros is forcing the java to print in the scientific format ? 

example
```
System.out.println("with stripTrailingZeros: " + new BigDecimal("-50").stripTrailingZeros());

System.out.println("without stripTrailingZeros: " + new BigDecimal("-50"));
```

Answer (score 8):

It's the implicit `.toString()` conversion that is happening when you pass the result into `System.out.println()`.

Answer (score 4):

The exact rationale for the behaviour of `BigDecimal.toString()` is explained in the [API doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString()) in great (and near incomprehensible) detail.

To get a consistent (and locale-sensitive) textual representation, you should use [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's basically because you don't have enough significant digits. If you multiply something that only has 1 significant digit with 100, then you get something with only 1 significant digit. If it shows "10" then that basically says that it has 2 significant digits. The way to show it only has 1 significant digit is to show "1 x 10^1".

The following two decimals have the same value (10), but different "scales" (where they start counting significant digits; the top has 2 sig figs, the bottom has 1):

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(BigInteger.TEN, 0));  // prints 10
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ONE, -1)); // prints 1E+1
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a BigDecimal where the scale may not match your intended output, but you want to print the canonical value:

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("10.00");

System.out.println(value.toPlainString());  //prints "10.00"
```

and want it to print just "10". You get "10.00" because the scale is set to 2.

If you just use **value.stripTrailingZeros()**, then it prints "1E+1".

```
System.out.println(value.stripTrailingZeros());  // prints "1E+1"
```

So combine the strip zeros and the plain string to the strip zeros fixes the scale and the plain part prints the normal way:

```
System.out.println(value.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());  //prints "10"
```

Will print "10".

This could happen when the value is in a relational database and mapped in or perhaps by some other manipulation or operation.