# How to always display a BigDecimal object in full decimal format instead of scientific notation?

Tags: java, formatting, bigdecimal

I have a `BigDecimal` object, `myNumber`, with unknown length. For example: `12345678`.

I always want to divide this number by 1 million, so I do:

```
myNumber.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000000))
```

I get `12.345678.`

I want to display this as a string "`12.345678`", without cutting off ANY decimal places.

So I do

```
myNumber.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000000)).toString()
```

This works fine with the above example. But if myNumber is something ridiculously small or big, such as:

```
0.00000001
```

After dividing `0.00000001` by a million and converting to string, it displays as scientific notation, which is not what I want. I want it to always display in full decimal format (in this case, `0.00000000000001`).

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Java BigDecimal return 1E+1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925232/why-does-java-bigdecimal-return-1e1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to perform the division using the variant of `divide()` that includes a rounding mode and a scale, and set the scale large enough to include all the fractional digits.

```
int s = myNumber.scale();
BigDecimal result = myNumber.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000000), s+6, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);
```

Then use `toPlainString()` to format.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [BigDecimal.toPlainString()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()) is the method you need. However, note that the division itself will throw an exception when the decimal representation is infinite, such as with 1/3.

Comment: Can you give an example of where `toString()` doesn't throw an exception and `toPlainString()` does?

Comment: @polygenelubricants: It was my mistake, I fixed the response. The ArithmeticException occurs when dividing. A BigDecimal can not handle infinite decimal representation.

Comment: yes, I asked that question on stackoverflow =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749375/arithmeticexception-thrown-during-bigdecimal-divide

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal.toString or toPlainString would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BigDecimal.toPlainString()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29) to return "a string representation of this `BigDecimal` without an exponent field".

The scientific notation on the other hand is returned by [`BigDecimal.toEngineeringString()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toEngineeringString%28%29).