# Issue with subtract in Bigdecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Hi  there this operation give me undesired response , how i can get desired response from it ?

For example when a and second is equal :

```
a=a.subtract(second);

a=0.99999905050206647416680425521917641162872314453125

second=1.0
```

give me

```
a=-9.4949793352583319574478082358837127685546875E-7
```

but i don't want it and i want numerical value not ...E-7 . How i can solve this ?
i tried this method but doesn't solve my problem.

```
a=a.setScale(15,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: How have you created the instances of `BigDecimal`, using `double` or using a `String` with the proper value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Java BigDecimal return 1E+1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925232/why-does-java-bigdecimal-return-1e1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`BigDecimal.toPlainString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29):

> Returns a string representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent field.